# Python - Unpacking a list in a dictionary to a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary that contains a list:

```py
d = {'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': 'hello'}
```

I want to unpack it in a list of dictionaries like this:

```py
l = [{'A': 1, 'B': 'hello'}, 
     {'A': 2, 'B': 'hello'},
     {'A': 3, 'B': 'hello'}]
```

I tried with the following function:

```py
    def unpack_dict(dict_to_unpack):
        unpacked_dicts = []
        for key in dict_to_unpack:
            if type(dict_to_unpack[key]) is list:
                for value in dict_to_unpack[key]:
                    temp_dict = dict_to_unpack
                    temp_dict[key] = value
                    unpacked_dicts.append(temp_dict)
        return unpacked_dicts if unpacked_dicts else dict_to_unpack
```

But I get this as a result instead:

```py
[{'A': 3, 'B': 'hello'}, 
 {'A': 3, 'B': 'hello'}, 
 {'A': 3, 'B': 'hello'}]
```

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: `temp_dict = dict_to_unpack.copy()` you need to copy your dictionary and work on it, instead of making a reference

Comment: Please clarify your use-case. Do you *always* have one concrete value and the other as a list? Can you have multiple values of different length? What is your criteria for unpacking - does it have to be a list, an iterable, or something else?

Comment: `d1 = [{'A': entry,'B':'hello'} for entry in d['A']]` where d is ` {'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': 'hello'}`

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The dictionary can have more than two values, but at most one is a list of any length. The result should be a list of dictionaries (I realized that my function should return a list also if the input dictionary contains no lists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not copying a dictionary, but using the old dict: `temp_dict = dict_to_unpack`

You can do what you want with this code:

```
from copy import copy

d = {'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': 'hello'}
result = []
for i in d['A']:
    dct = copy(d)
    dct['A'] = i
    result.append(dct)
print(result)
```

> `[{'A': 1, 'B': 'hello'}, {'A': 2, 'B': 'hello'}, {'A': 3, 'B': 'hello'}]`

Comment: Perhaps better to mark the question as dupe instead of answering it?

Comment: Note that there is not need to import ``copy``, as ``dict`` already has a ``copy`` method.